# Sending data from an activity to an object on a 3rd party activity

Tags: android

In the course of creating an android library, I've learned I need to be able to open an activity from a generic library object and have the activity pass back data to the the library object. Normally, I would simply use startActivityForResult and call it a day, but in this case the library object will be using the client application's context. As such, any result would be sent to the client application and not to the library object.

So the flow would be something like this: Client instantiates our library object -> the library object determines it needs to present its own activity and does so -> library's activity returns data to the library object which can continue processing

I've tried a couple of different solutions but none seem to produce the desired results.

1. fragments - the issue I ran into here is that the fragment is tied to an activity which means it would need to somehow be tied to the client's activity in order for our object to get what it needs. So for our purposes this doesn't make sense to use.
2. Temporary splash screen - this is the route we're currently leaning towards since a basic splash screen would allow us to leverage our object on an activity we owned which could then call the activities it may need along the way and then return a response to the client's app in the activityForResult. The drawback of this design is that we were hoping to leverage a set of events which the client could code to when we fire them off. However this can be worked around if needed.
3. Also looked into leveraging the sharedPreferences but the issue there would be that when we returned to the client's activity we'd somehow need to "kick" the library to continue working. We don't want our clients to have to make multiple calls into our library. And spinning off a background thread to "poll" feels like very bad practice in this situation.

So what I'm looking for is whether the 2nd approach is really the only way to solve this or if there is another way in android development which I'm currently unaware of?

Comment: "library object which can continue processing", If you want to continue processing, you either need to put a loading spinner on the screen, block the UI in your activity and do what you want. Or create an Android service and do your processing in the background.

Comment: Tbh I could help, but your example doesn't have enough details. I know you might want to keep your business secret, but just write down a different example so we can understand a bit more :)